# Merging multiple cell in DynamicJasper

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

I'm using DynamicJasper for creating dynamic reports. I've been trying to achieve merging multiple cell when no data available, like following. I'm also using table borders and background color for odd rows in the table.
I need to remove background color in empty cell as well.

```
-------------------------------------------
|   Name   |  height |  weight |percentage|
|-----------------------------------------|
|    A     | 1.9     | 0.003   |   40%    |
|-----------------------------------------|
|    B     | 1.7                          |
-------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to achieve such thing using dynamicJapser. I've been searching answer over the internet for days. I'd really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a combination of styling and printWhenExpression you may manage to achieve that